# How to create a 2D array with strings AND floats?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

My infile.txt looks like this:

```
Takoma_store 2.7 71.3 14.7 23.9 51.2
Bethesda_store 12.7 8.9 17.8 7.9 18.3
Baltimore_store 123.5 134.8 564.6 451.8 521.9 1796.6
District_store 56.2 26.5 123.4 456.7 789.3 1452.1
Prince_store 23.1 28.3 12.9 120.0 45.8 230.1
Columbia_store 21.5 123.0 80.9 99.0 91.20 415.60
Bowie_store 100.0 100.0 100.0 100.0 100.0 100.0
```

And i need to create an array that looks like this

```
[Takoma_store] [2.7, 71.3, 14.7, 23.9, 51.2]
[Bethesda_store] [12.7, 8.9, 17.8, 7.9, 18.3]
[Baltimore_store] [123.5, 134.8, 564.6, 451.8, 521.9, 1796.6]
[District_store] [56.2, 26.5, 123.4, 456.7, 789.3, 1452.1]
[Prince_store] [23.1, 28.3, 12.9, 120.0, 45.8, 230.1]
[Columbia_store] [21.5, 123.0, 80.9, 99.0, 91.20, 415.60]
[Bowie_store] [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
```

using a two for loops. I understand that it needs to be formatted something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < number_of_stores; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < number_of_sales; y++) {
        //collect data from file
    }
}
```

**but I have no idea how to declare a multidimensional (2D) array that allows me to collect strings (name of the store) and floats (sales)**

Comment: Better data structure would be use `map<string, vector<double>>`, or  `unordered_map<string, vector<double>>`.

Comment: how about using `std::map`? like this : `std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>>`. if your names are not unique then you can use `std::multimap`.

Comment: @YamanJain I tried to do that, but it's an assignment and the teacher is making me use an array.

Comment: @Hamed I tried to do that, but it's an assignment and the teacher is making me use an array.

Comment: Then I guess you need to define a class or struct for it, I don't think it's possible with arrays, unless your numbers are also string and you convert them later.

Comment: May be you can use "number_of_stores"x2 array, and then convert the numbers to strings using `atoi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use `std::map` as you said in comments, your can do something like this with struct:

```
struct strdbl
{
    std::string name;
    double nums[6];
};

int main()
{
    strdbl sf[10] = {
        {"Takoma_store", {2.7, 71.3, 14.7, 23.9, 51.2}},
        {"Bethesda_store", {12.7, 8.9, 17.8, 7.9, 18.3}},
        {"Baltimore_store", {123.5, 134.8, 564.6, 451.8, 521.9, 1796.6}},
        {"District_store", {56.2, 26.5, 123.4, 456.7, 789.3, 1452.1}},
        {"Prince_store", {23.1, 28.3, 12.9, 120.0, 45.8, 230.1}},
        {"Columbia_store", {21.5, 123.0, 80.9, 99.0, 91.20, 415.60}},
        {"Bowie_store", {100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0}}
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a struct like in Hamed's answer is a possibilty.

Another way would be using [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) i.e. `std::variant<std::string, std::array<double, 6>>` then make an array of those.

Using C-arrays is really not very C-plus-plussy. But if your teacher likes naughty stuff you *really could* store both  `std::string` (or `char*`) **and** `double` in the same C-array, if you make an array of `void*` i.e.:

```
char* store = "Takoma_store";
double d1   = 2.7;
double d2   = 71.3;
...
void* list[] = { &store, &d1, &d2 ...};
```

To access i.e. `d1` you'd write `double d = *(double*)list[1];`. Oh my! Very nasty!

I can't think of anything more dirty in C++, your teacher might like it.
You could also make the `void*` array 2D and store `char*` (or whatever) in one dimension and `double`s in the other.